# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when trying to reverse an array

Tags: java, arrays

This seems simple enough but I get the error `"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at reverse.main(reverse.java:28)"`

I initially take inputs from the user to write an array, and then I want to print the array backwards. I understand there are other ways of doing this, but I mainly want to know why this is not working. Going through it line by line makes sense?

PS. If it's not a problem, is there any better way of doing this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class reverse {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printf("Enter the number of values in array: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n;
        n = scanner.nextInt();

        double[] a1 = new double[n];
        int i;

        System.out.printf("Enter the value in the array: ");
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
            Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(System.in);
            a1[i] = scanner2.nextInt();
            }
         double j;
         double k;

            for (i = 0; i < n/2; i++){
                j = a1[i];
                k = a1[n-i]; //error line;
                a1[i]=k;
                a1[n-i]=j;
            }
         for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        System.out.println(" "+a1[i]);
    }}


}
```

Comment: Why create a new `Scanner` when the old one is already reading from `System.in` just fine?

Comment: You should really learn to format your code, it will do you a favor in a near future, when your programs become more complicated!

Comment: `k = a1[n-i];` When you have minuses and other things when you try to calculate an *index*, please check **before** that the index is not out of bounds.

Answer (score 6):

When i = 0, n-i will result in n, which is one larger than the available indexes( 0 -> n-1 ).

```
for (i = 0; i < n/2; i++){
  j = a1[i];
  k = a1[n-i]; //error line;
  a1[i]=k;
  a1[n-i]=j;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's the explanation, but the code you gave is exactly the same.

Comment: I think they gave the same code and an explanation so the guy can fix it himself. Bit better to learn that way, no?

Comment: @user898465 For people coming and reading this question later, this will confuse them. Either fix the code or don't include it in the answer (since it implies it's the correct solution).

Comment: Or just use my answer below ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(array))
```

Will reverse an array for you, then just print its values out. It's great to do these kinds of problems as exercises but if you're ever woring in the industry it's usually better to rely on the Java API for trivial things like this. Probably going to be faster and a lot more simpler than anything you can come up with.

Comment: Worth noticing that the array must be declared using a wrapper class (i.e here `Double[] array`), otherwise it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As said by Samhain, when `i = 0`, then `n-i == n`, which is greater than the last index of the array (since arrays start with index 0).

The simplest solution is to just subtract an additional 1 from `n-i`.

```
j = a1[i];
k = a1[n-i-1];
a1[i]=k;
a1[n-i-1]=j;
```

Also, creating a new `Scanner` is totally unnecessary. Just continue to use the first one you created.

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    a1[i] = scanner.nextInt();
}
```

Finally, for what it's worth, if you're using `nextInt` you don't need to declare your array as a `double[]` (nor do `j` and `k` need to be doubles). You can just use ints.

Here's it running on [ideone](http://ideone.com/Vdhx0k).